# Convert C# user control to MVC 5 partial

Tags: model-view-controller

I have several web form pages to convert that all use the same user control. The user control does the following:

- Displays a list of data with multiple links used to update the
  display or load a new display

  - A link to mark item to show in another area
  - A link to load that particular page
  - A link to delete that particular list item
- Contains a button/modal combination to create a new item to add to the list or edit the name of the existing item already selected

When a new item is created/updated it reads through all the asp.net controls on the page to save that data to a database.

I have created a model to replace the controls on the page that includes a class for the items related to the user control. Each page now contains one Html.BeginForm and inside that form I render @Html.Partial("_SavedList", Model.SavedLists). For each link, I'm using:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("UpdateList", "SavedList", new { title = "Current Title" })">Update</a>
```

The links do post back to the controller if I don't include any parameters but I don't have or don't understand how to access the whole model (not just the saved lists). I've been seeing tons of examples of controller methods handling just the class for the partial view but I"m struggling to find any that access the whole updated model. How do I get the data for the whole model and the partial view?

View model sample:

```
public class WholeViewModel
{
    public Criteria Crit {get;set;}
    public SavedList SavedLists {get;set; } 
}
```

Changed to form action like so:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateList", "SavedList", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "", @role = "form", vm = Model }))
  {
     <input type="submit" id="btn-save" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
  }
```

Comment: `Url.Action` sends the request as URL with query string. If you want to pass all viewmodel properties as viewmodel class name, use a form with POST request.

Comment: Unfortunately, just setting a button inside a form with post is not returning the current  updated view model either.